# defining a map with value as array

Tags: matlab

how can I define a map, so the key is uint32 and the value is array of int32?

there is an option to define that `valueSet` but `keySet` has to be also defined with it.

I need a single key to array of integers. I will be happy for example.

thanks in advanced.

**EDIT**
value as struct is ok also

Comment: Why not use cell arrays?

Comment: as value right? how do you define it?

Comment: myvar{123} = [1 2 3 4 5];

Comment: Have you tried the map datastructure. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/overview-of-the-map-data-structure.html

Comment: @RobertStettler Using a cell array as you suggested would be extremely memory intensive the moment you have key with a high numerical value.

Comment: @hiandbaii, that article explain the properties of map, its ok, but it doesnt explains how to define array as value in a map and how to access it.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html . Here's the article for the actual functions.

Comment: @hiandbaii, note that if you use the `valueSet` (an array of 1xn), the `keySet` has to be the same size as `valueset`. my question is how to config the map so the key will be just a number and the value will be struct or array.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `KeyType` when creating your map but if you have values of different sizes you have to keep `ValueType` as `any`. For example:

```
mapObj = containers.Map('KeyType','uint32','ValueType','any')
mapObj(2) = int32([1 2 3 4])
>> mapObj(2)

ans =

       1           2           3           4
```

Obviously the downside is that you can specify some key to take a value of a different type too. Like:

```
mapObj(3) = 'name'
```

But I can't imagine this being any real issue in your program. Also a `ValueType` of `struct` is not supported yet so you are better off keeping your values as arrays.